# Dual Input Voltage source single output question

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to make a circuit that will have 2 power sources. One will be be a main and one will be a battery backup. When backup or main is disconnected I want to make sure that the supplies are not being put into the other. (like a battery backup circuit) However most of those that i saw use 2 diodes. Ones on each of the positive rails.

I have wondered why not use mosfets to do this as they have a diode built in. But I can't seem to understand the datasheet. It seems that source to drain voltage is -1.5v so I won't be able to do it in this case. But I thought that power mosfets are used in some circuits this way. Here is my circuit. I have 2 irf9520 p channel mosfets I can use. I want them to also work as reverse voltage protection and in their current configuration I know they will work for that. But I'm not sure if this configuration will cause an issue with that also.
I have kept away from the diodes as they cause to much of a voltage drop. The load takes 7v minimum and the battery backup does not last that long so I would prefer that method.

[image]

I believe I'm not reading the datasheet right. Can anyone tell me if this will work ? If it will not work can you help with an explanation and possible a circuit to be able to do this. Thanks.

Load current draw is between 25ma and 200ma. Being held mainly at 170ma.

Comment: The body diode of a MOSFET should not be used to conduct significant amounts of current.

Comment: @Hearth how would it be conducting current in this manner ?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking.

Comment: What would be significant amounts of current then ? I added my current draw of my load to the question.